# how to get rid of the a "invisible border" on hover

Tags: html, border

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with only a right border, but when I do this, there's like an invisible left border on the hover, which does not fully make the border the color I want it to be. (a part of the left side is blue instead of light blue)

This is the CSS

```
 #navbar{

    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#3f67c0;
    height:60px;


    }
#navbar ul {  
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: left; 
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px; 
    } 

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline-block;

    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    display:block;
    border-right:#FFF solid 1px;
    border-left:none;
    border-top:none;
    boder-bottom:none;
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;  
    } 

#navbar ul li a:hover { 

    color: #FFF; 
    background-color: #35b5eb;

    }
```

This is the HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CLAIM</a></li>
<li><a href="#">PROOF</a></li>
<li><a href="#">HELP</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the space in the HTML as well as a combination of `display: inline-block` and its `display: block` child.  The best solution is to remove said space

```
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li
><li><a href="#">CLAIM</a></li>...
```

You could also use `font-size: 0` on the `ul` and the necessary `font-size` on the `<li>` or `<a>`, or use `float: left` on the `<li>` instead of `display: inline-block`, but these may result in other artifacts

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zPjCS/

Comment: hmm that's interesting Thank you for the reply, I thought white space had no effect on well anything in html